# VF getting a value from a look up field and run it against my SOQL Query

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, custom

I am new to Apex and VF so I was wondering if someone can help me. I have a custom object Story_Task__c, a parent object Story__c, and another parent object to Story called Sprint__c.
I have created a lookup filed on my VF page:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!stt.Owner__c}"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!s.Sprint__c.Name}"/>
```

And I am trying to run a Query in my custom controller, that is taking the result of the lookup field and is running it against the query.

```
public Story__c s { get;set; }
public Sprint__c sp { get;set; }
public Story_Task__c stt { get;set; }

getStoryTasks = [Select Id, Name, Owner__r.Name, Story__r.Name, Subject__c, Story__r.Sprint__r.Name
FROM Story_Task__c 
WHERE Owner__c=:stt.Owner__c AND Story__r.Sprint__r.Name =:s.Sprint__c.Name];
```

I am getting results for the Owner, by my query is not returning anything for the Sprint name.

Thanks

Comment: Did this code compile without errors? You are using __c.Name?

Comment: Yes It is. In my query if I do Story__r.Sprint__r.Name = 'Sprint Name", my query and and my VF page returns results. But for some reason when I want to grab the value from the field.
<apex:inputField value="{!s.Sprint__c.Name}"/> I am not getting any results. So I am thinking that I am not getting the value from the field correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using lookup field for Sprint__c, then use that as inputField
It will automatically show the name and id will exist underline.

```
<apex:inputField value="{!stt.Owner__c}"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!s.Sprint__c}"/>
```

**Controller**

Verify the relationship properly in SOQL query. I have given a sample for this on how to fetch records based on `s.Sprint__c`

```
getStoryTasks = [Select Id, Name, Owner__r.Name, Story__r.Name, 
Subject__c, Story__r.Sprint__c, Story__r.Sprint__r.Name
FROM Story_Task__c 
WHERE Owner__c=:stt.Owner__c 
AND Story__r.Sprint__c =:s.Sprint__c];
```

Comment: This Worked. Thank you so much. I did try that option earlier and not sure why it did not work and it does. Thanks